# Code Consistency badge for packages using PHP_CodeSniffer

Tags: github-pages, phpcodesniffer

The [PHP_CodeSniffer Github](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) page has a very nice **Code Consistency** badge.

[image: image link]

Clicking the badge takes you to a breakdown of the analysis for the ranking reported by the badge.  You can also see the [analysis of many packages](https://squizlabs.github.io/PHP_CodeSniffer/analysis/).

I would like to include a **Code Consistency** badge in my own projects.

I can not find any details for how this is achieved.  Perhaps it's not something that is available to any packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add projects manually to that analysis site, but you can suggest a PHP project to add by opening an issue on the PHP_CodeSniffer Github project. It must be hosted on Github though, and be public.

The information I need is pretty basic. You can view the list of current projects, and their settings, here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/gh-pages/analysis/_assets/repos.json

The settings are:

- Name: The friendly name of your project
- URL: The Github path to your project
- Path: The path inside your project to check (most use either the root, or `src` if your root has a bunch of files and dirs that should not be checked)
- Ignore: Any files or directories to ignore, using one of more regexs (if your git clone is going to have code from other projects in it)
- Extensions: In case you use non-standard extensions, which ones should be checked.

If you have no idea what the settings should be, you can point me to a Github repo and I can figure it out, as I've done for the vast majority of projects in the report.